How to Accurately Check Cycle Time for LIN Messages
How to Calculate Cycle Time for LIN Messages from ARXML or LDF Files
My Approach

From ARXML Files:

Extract the schedule tables for each cluster.

Identify the specific signal/message of interest within each schedule table for specific cluster.

Sum the delays for this specific signal.



From LDF Files:

Extract the schedule tables for specific cluster.

Identify the specific signal/message of interest.

Sum the delays for this specific signal across all schedule tables.




My Questions

Is this the correct approach to calculate the cycle time for a specific LIN message?

Are there any best practices or tools that can help automate this process?


Example
Scheadule_tables
{
    table1
    {
        signal1 : delay 10 ms,
        signal2 : delay 20 ms
    }
    table2
    {
        signal1 :delay 10 ms
    }
    table3
    {
        signal2: delay 20 ms
    }
 }

so in this scenario:
cyclicity time for signal 1 will be 20ms and cyclicity time for signal2 will be 40ms is this correct?
